# Is there anyway to use bootstrap's popover on div tags?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Bootstrap's popover is easily used on  tags like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/) Is there any way to use it with hover event and on a div tag?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with data-trigger</a>
    <a id="popoverOption" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title">Popup with option trigger</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mytext').popover();
$('#name').popover();
```

Comment: Simply add the proper annotations on a div tag, and call the popover() method on it. The BS popover code is not specific to a particular type of tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure why not?

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/2892/

**html**

```
<div id="container" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title">
    Whatever you want.
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#container').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```